# Booking System and Drop-Down Menus

Tags: php, mysql

I wish to create a booking system using PHP and MySQL which enables customers to select the event from a dynamic drop-down menu and book a stall that is available

I have created a working drop-down menu  and the code works perfectly:

```
$SQL="SELECT * from Things";
$exeSQL=mysql_query($SQL);
{
echo "<select>";
while($arrayThings = mysql_fetch_array($exeSQL))
{
echo"<br><option>{$arrayThings['ThingName']}</option>";
}
echo "</select>";

}
```

How can I allow that once the selection has been made from the drop-down and the customer proceeds, for that choice be taken into consideration and the stall be booked accordingly?

I hope that explanation was clear!

Thanks in advance for your help!

EDIT: I placed my drop down in a form not exactly sure if I did it right or how to link it on my next page

```
$SQL="SELECT * from Things";
$exeSQL=mysql_query($SQL);
{
echo "<form method=post action=booking.php>" ;
echo "<input type=hidden name=id value=$arrayThings[thingId]>";
echo "<select>";
while($arrayThings = mysql_fetch_array($exeSQL))
{
echo"<br><option>{$arrayThings['thingName']}</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
echo "</form>" ;
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution would be to wrap all that code around a form, then check if the form has been posted. If the form is posted, then get the value that's selected (you'll need to give your select a name) and perform your database insert / booking.

Comment: Would you happen to know how to link it to my next page? Would I use an SQL query?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to give each `option` some sort of `value` attribute.  This could be for example the ID in the database, though for live systems, this is not recommended, you should create some sort of ID system that may use custom web IDs for `option` `values` instead of the IDs used in DB tables.  You will now have an ID for you to use in your booking system, in order to book that particular stall

For example, you could place the `select` box in a form and have the action of the `form` to be `makeBooking.php`, that would pass the `value` of the selected `option` along with any other data you may need, e.g. `user` ids etc.  In makebooking.php, you would have the logic to perform the booking logic and return a success / failure response to the client

Comment: I'm quite new to PHP so sorry for the stupid questions! When placing it in a form would I do it like this: [Edited post above to show the code]